# Please verify my epsilon - delta proof $\lim_{x\to 2}⁡(x^3 )=8,$ and $0 < x < 4$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

I am concern about the delta calculation given $0 < x < 4$.
I believe it works, but I am not 100 percent sure as I am new to proofs.

Consider the function $f(x) = x^3$ for $x ∈ ℝ$ and $0 < x < 4$. Prove that $$\lim _{ x\rightarrow 2 }{ { x }^{ 3 }=8 } $$

**Proof**: Let $\varepsilon  > 0$ be given, then let $\delta =  \min   {(\varepsilon/19,1)}$. Now suppose $|x -2| < \delta = \min {(\varepsilon /19,1)}$.
Then $|x^3 - 8| = |x - 2||x^2 + 2x + 4|< |x - 2|<19$ 
$(|x^2 + 2x + 4| < 19~\text{if}~|x - 2| < 1)< \varepsilon /19 $ 
$(|x - 2| < \varepsilon /19 )= \varepsilon $.

Thus this $\delta$ makes $|x^3 - 8| < \varepsilon $ whenever $0 < |x - 2| < \delta$. Therefore, it follows that $\lim _{ x\rightarrow 2 } x^3 = 8$.

Comment: Whoever started editing this, how about finishing the job?

Comment: Sorry, I tried to edit delta to epsilon-delta in the first line, but it would not take.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: If the main purpose of your question is supposed to be verification and critique of your approach (as opposed to asking for any proof of this fact), you could use ([tag:proof-verification]) tag. See [the tag-info](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/proof-verification/info) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Need some improvement in presentation.

If $|x-2|< \delta = \min(\epsilon/19,1),$

then we have $x \in (1,3)$ and hence $|x^2+2x+4|<19.$

Hence, for $|x-2|< \delta$, we have $$|x^3-8|=|x-2||x^2+2x+4|< (\epsilon/19)(19)=\epsilon $$

Remark:

The line $|x-2||x^2+2x+4|<\left|x-2\right|$  is wrong in your proof.

Comment: Is the calculation 19 correct for 0<x<4?

Comment: Yes, notice that $x^2+2x+4=(x+2)^2 $ is convex and nonnegative. To find the largest number, just check the boundary. The maximum is attained at $x=3$.

Comment: I only consider $1<x<3$ since we let $\delta<1$.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a simpler road is this.

let $\epsilon \in R^+$
$$|x^3-8|<\epsilon$$
now substitute $x \to t+2$, and the condition becomes:
$$
|t^3+6t^2+12t|<\epsilon
$$
if we choose $|t| < \min\{\epsilon/19,1\}$ the condition is respected and by back substitution:
$$|x-2| < \min\{\epsilon/19,1\}\equiv\delta \implies |x^3-8|<\epsilon$$
which is the definition of limit.