# Limits of functions proof help $\lim_{x\to 2} \left(x^3\right) = 8$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Can anyone help me finish this proof?

Prove that $$\lim_{x\to 2} \left(x^3\right) = 8$$

$|x^3-8|=|(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)|=|x-2|<1$
$$1<x<3$$

Comment: Related: [Proof verification using the same technique](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1870711/please-verify-my-epsilon-delta-proof-lim-x-to-2x3-8-and-0-x-4).

Comment: you don't need to use limits where there are no issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|(x-2)(x^2+2x+4)| \ne |x-2|$, I'm not sure where you were getting that equality, but you're on the right track. However it looks like you're trying to use $\epsilon - \delta $, so you need to build it up correctly first.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. We need to find a $\delta$ such that $|x-2| < \delta $ implies $|x^3 - 8| < \epsilon $

You have complete control over your choice of delta, so let's arbitrarily let $\delta  < 1$. Then we have
$|x - 2| < 1$, so that $x <3$ and $x^2 < 9$. Putting this together we get that $|x^2 +2x+4| < 19$.

Now let $\delta = \min${$1, \epsilon / 19$}.  Then $|x - 2| < \delta$ implies $|x^3 - 8| = |x-2||x^2 + 2x + 4| < 19|x - 2| < \epsilon$.

The desired result follows.

Answer (score 0):

Here $x-2 \to 0\ \implies x^3-8\to 0$

And if $a-b\to 0\ \implies a\to b$

Hence $$\lim_{x\to0}x^3=8$$

Comment: OP is most likely asking for an ($\epsilon$-$\delta$) proof.

Comment: It is already there as another question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1870711/417228

Answer (score 0):

$|x|=|x-2+2| \leqslant |x-2|+2$

thus $|x^2+4x+4|=(x+2)^2 \leqslant (|x-2|+2)^2$

thus $|x^3-8| \leqslant |x-2|(|x-2|^2+4|x-2|+4)$.

Now  if you take $\delta <1$ you have that $|x^3-8|<9|x-2|$(because we are interested more in very small values of $\delta$).

Finally you can choose $\delta=\min\{\frac{\epsilon}{9},1\}$ to have $|x^3-8|< \epsilon$

Comment: wait how did $|x^2+4x+4|=(x+2)^2$ ?

Comment: $|x^2+4x+4|=|(x+2)^2|=|(x+2)|^2=(x+2)^2$  because $(x+2)^2 $ is non negative

Comment: Sorry I am just a little confused as where did you get the $|x^2+4x+4|$ from?  The rest of the proof I understood very well.

Comment: $x^3-8=(x^4+2x+4)(x-2)$..you also mentioned that above.